# Building web-page

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

```
      <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>My web page</title>
  <link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <h1>Welcome to my page!</h1>
  <body>
  <nav id="nav">
  <ul>

  <li>Home</li>

  <li><a href="">About Me!</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="">Me!</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Hobbies!</a></li>
  <li><a href="">My Photography!</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Favorite Music!</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="">Important Links</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="">L1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">L2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">L3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">L4</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
  </nav>
      <img src="http://http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Sydney_harbour_bridge_new_south_wales.jpg" width="700" height="400"  alt=""/>
  <p>About Me</p>
  <p>About Me</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS file...

```
      * {
          text-align:center;
  }

  h1 {
  }

  nav {
      display: block;
      font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #202020;
      list-style-type: none;
  }

  p {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: 202020;
      position: relative;
  }

  img {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  }


  #nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      float: none;
      padding-top: 5px;
      background-color: #ACFE89;
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      color: #333366;
  }

  #nav ul li:hover {
      color: #0099FF;
  }
  #nav ul li ul{
        display:none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
  }
  #nav ul li ul li{


      }
  #nav ul li:hover > ul {
      display:block;
  }
  a {
      text-decoration: none;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/txZ5K/3/

Hi, i'm facing some problems with this page...

The drop down menus are messed up.
Drop down menus are gone behind the image.
All the items on the navigation bar doesn't highlight on hover.

I'm new at this but trying my best to make a cool page. Please please help me!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/t2XfH/

i gave a `z-index` of 10 to `#nav ul`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1) In your CSS style named - `#nav ul li` change the `padding-left` as well as `padding-right` to 20 px.

```
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

2) In your CSS named `#nav ul li ul li`, add `width:130px;` like

```
#nav ul li ul li {
  width:130px;
}
```

Try this & still if you face any issue..let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Well, issue here stack order of elements i,e.

```
 <img src="http://http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons
   /a/a8/Sydney_harbour_bridge_new_south_wales.jpg" width="700" height="400"  alt=""/>
     <p>About Me</p>
     <p>About Me</p>
```

is before the dropdown menu in stack .so specifying `z-index` for drop-down will help,
The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element and element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

```
      #nav ul {
         z-index: 1;
      }
```

in you case setting it '1' will be enough.

I changed code a bit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2XfH/2/)